# Sci-fi movie about a gigantic Russian submarine

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

The movie starts with a rescue crew looking for a missing research submarine that vanished in very deep water. The rescue crew finds the missing research vessel and finds it to be full of holes, "eaten" away badly by fast-acting, iron-eating bacteria – the reason it sank.

While looking for the first missing submarine, they happen to be behind a large outcropping of rock just as a powerful sonar pulse sweeps by and hits the sea floor. Their onboard radiation detectors show that, if they had been in the direct line of the blast, they would have been irradiated to death.

The rescue crew now finds itself with malfunctions and their own vessel in peril (due to the aggressive bacteria), and pretty much lose all hope. Nearly a day goes by with them trying to figure out a way to resurface but to no avail. A gigantic submarine slowly drifts over them from out of no where, then latches on and hauls them into its bay.

The gigantic submarine seems deserted and this confuses the rescue crew as they wonder who just saved them. Later, they find the crewman that saved them badly irradiated and begging for help near the lift controls in the bay, the only reason the crewman brought them on board. Long story short, the submarine is a gigantic research vessel of Russian origin searching for oil illegally. The submarine is nearly deserted as it had its own accident; its nuclear, high-power sonar accidentally activated in the up position in the bay, killing nearly all the crew.

The gigantic submarine is also slowly being eaten away by the iron eating bacteria and the rescue crew eventually find the madman captain and a surprise in the form of the wife of one of the rescuers long thought dead, lost at sea years ago.

Language: English. Time period in movie, modern day. Time period the movie was out, I watched it on Amazon Prime 2 years ago, so it is within 5-7 years old. No big name actors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually mini-series [The Deep](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1525182/combined) from 2010 starring Minnie Driver and James Nesbitt.

> Captain Frances Kelly (Driver) leads a **research team below the Arctic ice aboard the cutting-edge submarine Orpheus in a quest to solve the world's burgeoning energy crisis and establish the fate of a doomed previous expedition, and expedition that took the wife of Kelly's chief engineer (Nesbitt).** Enduring crushing pressure, violent volcanic gas eruptions, freezing temperatures and total darkness, the Orpheus arrives at the Lomonosov Ridge, an area of seabed within disputed territory under United Nations' administration and monitoring. Nobody ever goes there **but there is something else in the freezing depths: something huge, a behemoth of epic proportions**, menace and unknown purpose.

...Which is a huge Russian submarine called Volos. And it contains everything you described: There are some strange lava worms (?) that excrete acid (?!) which is corroding the submarine; they find that missing wife alive, along with an insane captain; the radiation, the illegal oil drilling, it's all there. See if this preview rings any bells:

Comment: Bingo, Nice hit. This is the "Movie", and it was in movie form not a series as it is shown when first released, though it was likely spliced together for amazon and shown in a non series format as the DVD suggests. Thanks so much! I guess I forgot about Mini driver as I do not care for her as an actress heh. Walt, you are the man.